# checking if a variable is defined

Tags: variable-definitions

How can I check if a variable is defined?

```
Definition[foo]
```

produces: `Null`, but:

```
Definition[foo]===Null
```

produces: `False`. (Clearly I do not want `==`.)

I want to use this (at least) for checking whether `$FrontEnd` is defined, in order to set some options.

Comment: If you want *all* of the definition info, check out the relatively secret ``Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[foo]``.

Comment: Also, I think something tricky is happening with `Definition[foo]`. Note that if something really does evaluate to `Null`, e.g. `3;`, it's not printed in the following `Out` cell. `Definition[foo] // FullForm` returns `Definition[foo]`. I'm not sure what's intervening here to make it appear as `Null`—maybe `Definition` has some built in `FormatValues` or something. (`Definition[foo]` remains as `Definition[foo]` in `FullForm` even when `foo` is defined.)

Comment: Oh, I forgot—if you want something less heavy duty than my first comment, check out [`ValueQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ValueQ.html). (It has a `Method` option for tweaking its behavior, too.)

Comment: `Definition` is not really meant for programming. It's a way for you, a human, to see the definition, not to manipulate them programmatically. `Definition[foo]` does not actually evaluate to `Null`. It merely _formats_ (i.e. displays) as `Null`, similar to how `Graphics[Disk[]]` displays as the image of a disk (and not as the literal text `Graphics[Disk[]]`).

Comment: Thank you thorimur for the `ValueQ` workaround. And thank you @Szabolcs for your explanation. I guess I can use `FullFrom`, as suggested by thorimur, as a simple way to check (in a different case) whether something evaluates to `Null`, or just formats it that way.

Comment: Hi. I am reopening this. I have a workaround, checking whether Head[$FrontEnd]===FrontEndObject. However I do not understand how on one hand, Invoking `ValueQ[$FrontEnd]` with any of the `Method` options all evaluated to `True`. But OTOH, `SetOptions[$FrontEnd,...]` continues to claim that it cannot set an option for `Null`, seemingly `$FrontEnd == Null`, and not just `Print`ing that way.